# An FSM with object state in Java

Tags: java, oop, fsm, state-machine

I'm implementing a Finite State Machine in java classes. I wasn't able to find another example with the states and events being their own objects (perhaps there's a reason to that?), and I'm not quite convinced with my solution, especially because I have to assign a state to the FSM (the actual manager) and then assign the FSM to the state (to notify a state change). Here's the code for the state manager, to which I assign a state, and spits it out if asked to:

```
public class FSM {

    public void setCurrentState(FSMState newCurrentState) {
        this.currentState = newCurrentState;
    }

    private FSMState currentState;

    public FSMState getCurrentState() {
        if (this.currentState == null)
            System.out.println("No current state");
        return this.currentState;
    }
}
```

and here's the state, that uses a map to map event to output state, and in case of a transition, notifies the FSM class:

```
public class FSMState implements EventListener {

    private FSM managingFSM;
    private Map<Event,FSMState> transitions;

    public FSMState(FSM managingFSM) {
        this.transitions = new HashMap<Event, FSMState>();
        this.managingFSM = managingFSM;
    }

    public void addEventTransition(Event event, FSMState outputState){
        transitions.put(event, outputState);
        event.registerListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void eventOccured(Event e) {
        FSMState newState = transitions.get(e);
        this.managingFSM.setCurrentState(newState);
    }
}
```

Is there a way, with a kind of similar solution, so that the state wouldn't have to notify the manager?

Comment: This looks very bug-prone. When do you add event transitions to the FSMStates? Because the way you have done it right now, when an Event occurs, it will fire in whatever FSMState it was registered (regardless of what the current state is) and change the current state.

I'm guessing you want only the events for the current state to get fired, so that you get the correct transition.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your implementation needs quite a few changes. Firstly, you probably want to create the states and their transitions before create the FSM itself. I would make a separate class to manage the initialisation and setup called FSMManager.

First change FSMState to be simply this:

```
public class FSMState {

    private Map<Event,FSMState> transitions;

    public FSMState() {
        this.transitions = new HashMap<Event, FSMState>();
    }

    public void addEventTransition(Event event, FSMState outputState){
        transitions.put(event, outputState);
    }

    public FSMState transition(Event e) {
        if(transitions.containsKey(e)) {
            return transitions.get(e);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No transition found");
            return this;
        }
    }

}
```

Then change the FSM class to look like this:

```
public class FSM implements EventListener {

    private FSMState currentState;

    public FSM(FSMState startState) {
        currentState = startState;
    }

    public FSMState getCurrentState() {
        if (this.currentState == null)
            System.out.println("No current state");
        return this.currentState;
    }

    @Override
    public void eventOccured(Event e) {
        currentState = currentState.transition(e);
    }
}
```

Finally add the manager to initialise everything:

```
public class FSMManager {

    private static final NUM_STATES = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         FSMState[] states = new FSMState[NUM_STATES];

         for(FSMState state : states) {
             state = new FSMState();
         }

         // Then add all the state transitions to all the states
         states[0].addEventTransition(event1, states[1]);
         states[1].addEventTransition(event1, states[2]);
         states[1].addEventTransition(event2, states[4]);
         // etc, etc

         //Finally, create the FSM
         FSM fsm = new FSM(state[0]);

         //You will also have to register the FSM to listen for all the events
         event1.registerListener(fsm);
         event2.registerListener(fsm);
         ...


    }

}
```

I don't know where you are getting all the `Events` from and how they are actually fired, but the above pattern is a good one to follow. This way when an event is fired, it will only be applied to the current state. The same events will produce different transitions in different states, as they would in a state machine.

This solution should help however it is not perfect as I do not know exactly how you are doing this, so if you have any questions/further problems comment and I will try to improve my answer.